# How to calculate the Final Total sum and calculate percentages

Tags: sql, postgresql, percentage, postgresql-9.3

Below I have a query where I have the total 1st language spoken by students in each language

CTE

```
WITH Lang AS
(
    SELECT  
        language, 
        studentcount,
        SUM(Studentcount) AS total
    FROM    
        (SELECT 
             l.longtext AS language,
             COUNT(distinct s.studentnr) AS Studentcount
         FROM 
             student s
         JOIN
             pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid
         JOIN
             pupillanguage pl on pl.personid = p.id
         JOIN
             language l on l.id = pl.languageid
         GROUP BY 
             l.longtext
         ORDER BY 
             Studentcount DESC
        ) t 
    GROUP BY 
        language, Studentcount
)
```

Query

```
SELECT initcap(language), Studentcount, total
FROM Lang 

UNION ALL

SELECT cast(count(language) as varchar(6)) ||' Languages', null, null
FROM Lang
```

Now I have 1 major issue which is assigning a TOTAL SUM value of students. I need this so I can calculate the **percentage** of **numbers of students / total students** in a column. However obviously my total value is not giving me what I need.

Output

```
    languages   students    total
    ------------------------------
    French        734        734
    Afrikaans      93         93
    Greek         117        117
    German         55         55
    Armenian      160        160
    Malaysian       5          5
    Danish         15         15
    American        5          5
    Swedish        24         24
    Bulgarian     1043      1043
```

Expected output:

```
languages   students    Percentage
-----------------------------------
French        734          24,46
Afrikaans      93           3,12
Greek         117           3,9
German         55           1,83
Armenian      160           5,33
Malaysian       5           0,16
Danish         15           0,5
American        5           0,16
Swedish        24           0,8
Bulgarian     1043         34,76
```

How can I calculate the final total sum as a value to calculate the percentages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=baa260af605617fb93bd4273c184d368)

You could use window functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT
    language,
    students,
    SUM(students) OVER () as total,
    students::decimal / SUM(students) OVER () * 100 as percentage 
FROM
--- <YOUR QUERY>
```

The window function `SUM(students) OVER ()` sums up all values of the students column because no limiting frame is given in the `OVER` clause

The `::decimal` cast is necessary to get a float division (100 / 200 = 0.5) instead of an integer division (100 / 200 = 0).

Comment: my problem is calculating the total value properly. I need a variable to hold total number of students

Comment: `SUM(students) OVER ()` does it

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
with t1 as (           
        SELECT l.longtext as language,
       count(distinct s.studentnr) as Studentcount    
            FROM student s
                join pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid    
                join pupillanguage pl on pl.personid = p.id
                join language l on l.id = pl.languageid    
            group by l.longtext
            order by Studentcount desc
        ) select language,Studentcount, sum(Studentcount) over() as total,
      (Studentcount::float/sum(Studentcount) over())*100 as percentage
      from t1
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to add a decimal cast to your division? Otherwise it would be an integer division, wouldn't it?